# awk remote ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, awk

I have a bash script that run a remote awk command but I guess I haven't correctly escape specials characters since no file is generated on the remote server. Still I have no error.

My variables are declared locally and can be used remotely without issue (other part of the script confirm this).

```
ssh -q -t server '
        logfiles=$(find /var/log/httpd/ -type f -name *access_log -cmin -'"$past"')
        for log in $logfiles;
             awk -vDate=\`date -d'now-'"$past"' minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\` ' { if \(\$4 > Date\) print \$0}' $log | sort  |uniq -c |sort -n | tail | cut -d " " -f 11,15,16
        done
'
```

Thank you!

---

### **EDIT1:**

passing this script

```
#!/bin/bsh

logfiles=$(find /var/log/httpd/ -type f -name *access_log -cmin -120)
for log in $logfiles; do
        awk -vDate=`date -d'now-120 minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` ' { if ($4 > Date) print $0}' $log | sort  |uniq -c |sort -n | tail | cut -d " " -f 11,15,16 > /root/httpd.log;
done
```

like this works

ssh user@host < script.sh

When I run the same script from the console :

```
ssh -q -t $apache '     
logfiles=$(find /var/log/httpd/ -type f -name *access_log -cmin -120)
for log in $logfiles; do
awk -vDate=`date -d'now-120 minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` ' { if ($4 > Date) print $0}' $log | sort  |uniq -c |sort -n | tail | cut -d " " -f 11,15,16 > /root/httpd.log;
done'

    -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

So I tried to escape the parenthesis

```
ssh -q -t $apache '
logfiles=$(find /var/log/httpd/ -type f -name *access_log -cmin -120)
for log in $logfiles; do
awk -vDate=`date -d'now-120 minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` ' { if \($4 > Date\) print $0}' /var/log/httpd/royalcanin_com.access_log | sort  |uniq -c |sort -n | tail | cut -d " " -f 11,15,16 > /root/httpd.log;
done'
```

but then nothing is generated.

---

### EDIT2:

Having the file generated on the server but empty with this:

```
awk -vDate=\`date -d'now-120 minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\` ' { if '"($4 > Date)"' print $0}' $log | sort  |uniq -c |sort -n | tail | cut -d " " -f 11,15,16 > /root/httpd.log;done'
```

Comment: You are missing a `do` after your `for`, I think.

Comment: You need not escape `$` `(` etc

Comment: You also shouldn't loop over the output of find like that. It isn't safe for filenames with spaces or for filenames with shell metacharacters.

Comment: You must insert one o more blanks just before the opening single quote: `server '`

Comment: You also should post the error message.

Comment: I would suggest to write it as a script, as if it is going to run via terminal on remote system & then run it as `ssh user@host < script.sh`. This approach sometimes helps for nested escaping requirements...

Comment: Your entire `ssh` command is enclosed in single quotes and, so is the `awk` script inside it, so the start of your `awk` script is effectively ending the `ssh` command.

Comment: Maybe you can replace the single quotes around your `awk` script with '\'' - which is single quote, slash, single quote, single quote.

Comment: Passing code via SSH is very messy, just copy the code as a script to the server in question (since you have SSH configured anyway), and run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to escape your single quotes. For example, the first script…

```
ssh -q -t server '
        logfiles=$(find /var/log/httpd/ -type f -name *access_log -cmin -'"$past"')
        for log in $logfiles;
             awk -vDate=\`date -d'now-'"$past"' minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\` ' { if \(\$4 > Date\) print \$0}' $log | sort  |uniq -c |sort -n | tail | cut -d " " -f 11,15,16
        done
'
```

… must really be written as:

```
ssh -q -t server '
        logfiles=$(find /var/log/httpd/ -type f -name *access_log -cmin -'\''"$past"'\'')
        for log in $logfiles;
             awk -vDate=\`date -d'\''now-'\''"$past"'\'' minutes'\'' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\` '\'' { if \(\$4 > Date\) print \$0}'\'' $log | sort  |uniq -c |sort -n | tail | cut -d " " -f 11,15,16
        done
'
```